# Formula to use in respect to spatial resolution, to calculate the appropriate amount of random samples for QA of raster data

Tags: raster, data-quality, formula

I am trying to write a script that will automatically calculate the amount of random samples needed to compare my derived DEM data against my truth datasets.

The DEM data can vary in resolution from 1m, 5m, and 10m. I want the script to be able to identify the resolution of the data, the total area of the data, and then using those two variables, calculate how many random samples are required.

Is there a simple formula for calculating this?

This data is a DEM of the Earth that can range from the size of your average US county to an entire state. I know a formula like this grows exponential at some point once you get to a big enough area so I am trying to find something that will balance total points needed for a high confidence level (>90%) while also accounting for the exponential increase in points.

Comment: @PolyGeo I have reopened this because the question is not asking for code, but rather asking for a formula that can be used.

Comment: @Aaron If the question is about a formula rather than writing Python code then I think Python should not appear in the question or its tags.